# Qt -> QLocale::toDateTime() Strange bug, only fails trying to convert "the first Sunday of September, of any year"

Tags: qt, pyqt, qt5

This is very, very strange.

Using `QLocale::toDateTime()` to convert Datetime in CSV, this happens:

I've got 15.707 dates, from `1/jan/1990` to `31/dec/2032`, using format string `dd-MM-YYYY h:mm:ss`.

example:

```
{....}
15-12-2032 0:00:00
16-12-2032 0:00:00
17-12-2032 0:00:00
18-12-2032 0:00:00
19-12-2032 0:00:00
{....}
31-12-2032 0:00:00
```

Conversion works well, except for... each 1st sunday of september for each year!
[Image: Failing dates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2KAo.png)

(Edit: Give a code snippet here, how you test if result is valid or not)

What have I tested:

a) the input file is clean, only UTF8 chars, no rogue characters

b) Tested on 2 different PC's

c) Changed OS Regional settings (edit: which ones did you change?)

d) Changed input date separator from "-" to "/"

Special Note:

e) If I strip the time part "0:00:00" it works fine.
And again, why the only dates failing, in 46 years, are the 46 first sundays of september?

I'm trying to convert dates that came in as listing in a CSV format, to a proper date time.
From 15.706 files, only 46 fails...
all of them, are the first sunday of september of each day!

Comment: Your question is unclear. What does fail? Do you get errors? Please provide a [mre].

Comment: @misicmante The returned `QDateTime` data type got a possible "invalid" state, from `isValid() `. But Op should've worded that clearer. ESL, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll channel Sherlock Holmes here and would say that you're working in Chile or you're using their TZ.

If you read documentation:

> If the string can be parsed and represents an invalid date-time (e.g.
> in a gap skipped by a time-zone transition), an invalid QDateTime is
> returned, whose toMSecsSinceEpoch() represents a near-by date-time
> that is valid.

PS. You're using mix of ISO format ([`Qt::ISODate`](https://het.as.utexas.edu/HET/Software/html/qt.html#DateFormat-enum)) and Qt text format. FOr ISO it's `DD` and `YYYY`, for Qt it's `dd` and `yyyy`. Qt kind of corrects that, but that invites possibility of tripping edge cases.

By exclusion, we get only case possible: invalid time gap. In Chile clock is changed at 24:00 first Saturday of September, 0:00 of next Sunday doesn't exist.

Try check resulting epoch time in order to correct this error. Mainly it's a 24:00\0:00 notation problem.

Comment: That would be a fantastic guess - I'd love to hear if your conclusion was right.

Comment: "By exclusion, we get only case possible: invalid time gap. In Chile clock is changed at 24:00 first Saturday of September, 0:00 of next Sunday doesn't exist."

wow, This is actually the possible cause.
a) could, then, happen to other date conversions, on other countries' locale?
b) Should be reported to QT developers?

Comment: @SullyPanda76cl It's documented behaviour, matches system function behaviour in POSIX (ISO), and based on locale (what you give to QLocale constructor, otherwise that's default OS locale). Time zone data it takes is from data known to OS. `toMSecsSinceEpoch()` with consequent use of  `fromMSecsSinceEpoch()` would give right result in that case. It's not done automatically because something else maybe wrong and additional logic maybe needed. E.g. if that's Chile, why there is a 0:00? by their standard it's 24:00 followed by 00:01. But some time sources may be buggy and ISO allows 00:00.

Comment: @SullyPanda76cl so did I guess it's Chile or Easter island? because if it's not,then something odd with DST or format string. Btw, if using ISO or RFC format one can specify time zone: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#DateFormat-enum

Comment: yes @Swift-FridayPie, you guess it right!

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie, to the question "if that's Chile, why there is a 0:00" the answer is: because of SoftwareGore. My input is a csv, that local programmer decided to add the suffix "0:00:00" to al dates.

Answer (score 0):

```
QLocale::setDefault( QLocale( QLocale::Spanish, QLocale::Chile ) );
QLocale().toDateTime( "03-09-2023 0:00:00", "dd-MM-yyyy H:mm:ss" );
```

Returns a valid datetime on some machines and not others. So it appears there must be some local machine, setting apart from the Qt locale, that is being used by `QLocale().toDateTime()`. See also: https://forum.qt.io/topic/144308/qlocale-todatetime-issue/