# Time formatting in c++

Tags: c++, datetime, time, datetime-format

I have this chunk of code used to get local time instance.

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

std::time_t rawtime;
std::tm* timeinfo;
char buffer [80];
std::time(&rawtime);
timeinfo = std::localtime(&rawtime);
std::strftime(buffer, 80, "%d%m%Y_%H%M_bishan_", timeinfo);
```

Current local time is 02/02/2024 Morning 11:51AM
But the time instance produced by the code is 02022024_2351_bishan_.
How can I change to be 02022024_1151_bishan_3?

Comment: What string is stored in `timeinfo->tm_zone`?

Comment: printed out in cout << timeinfo << endl; this way is all hex data like 0xffff9741fe60

Comment: @batuman `cout << timeinfo` – This will print the address the `timeinfo` pointer is pointing at. No point in printing this. Instead, do `std::cout << timeinfo->tm_zone << '\n';`

Comment: ... or use the debugger and examine the value

Answer (score 4):

Why are you still using the "C" api. For anything regarding time in C++ use the `<chrono>` header. This really avoids problems with type safety, buffer issues (security) etc.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <format>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto local_now = std::chrono::current_zone()->to_local(now);

    // https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock/formatter
    // note the %I which will format hours in the 12 hour format
    std::cout << std::format("{:%d%m%Y_%I%M}_bishan_\n", local_now);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ironically, most implementations with date formatting are even less secure than using C API code for certain applications, but I doubt this is the case. Mostly in cases where date is illegal we have no control over what happened, C API gives diagnostics, at least on Linux, but if that important, *carefully* using OS API ( e.g. POSIX-compatible) is probably would be more correct.

Comment: Fair points, "carefully" is always important wrt security anyway ;)

Comment: Wouldn't want to output `local_now` since you calculated it? (code review mode)

Comment: @stefaanv Yup I should have done that, fixed

Comment: But using `%I` without `%p` will conceal the very fact that OP's timezone seems to be off by 12 hours! Quoting: _"Morning 11:51AM"_, but the output was ...2351.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Illegal dates are not possible in this answer.  But in other parts of the chrono API invalid dates *are* possible, and the programmer has 100% control of detecting and responding to them by utilizing the ubiquitous member function `.ok()`.

Comment: @HowardHinnant Thanks for clarifying, and for your library

Comment: @HowardHinnant you can't assume that system clock is always right :P And what if that another source, like a database? What happens in case similar to this case? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75915484/qt-qlocaletodatetime-strange-bug-only-fails-trying-to-convert-the-first/75921662#75921662

Comment: `system_clock::time_point` has no values that represent invalid dates.  Therefore `system_clock::now()` can't return an invalid date.  And getting the value from the underlying OS isn't going to help things.  `system_clock::now()` is just a thin but portable wrapper around the OS API.  If the source is a database it very much depends on what the database contains.  In the question you reference, local time is in the database (or at least that is how it is being interpreted).  chrono detects ambiguous and non-existent mappings from local time to UTC: http://eel.is/c++draft/time.zone.members#6

Comment: @Howard Hinnant oh, but it does, because in OS there is a representation of invalid dates. In result `system_clock::now()` returns "kind of" valid date, just in future or past. I just recently dealt with that,  rsult of bug i ntp software of peripheral navigational device (interal clock goes too fast and triggers bug in NTP software). It broke entire netwrk, by causign all CAs repeatedly  revoke and re-issue their certificates until they ran out of allocated space in revoked certificates list.